# Referencing a project using Google Calendar API on net 4.0 does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0, google-calendar-api

I have VS2013 C# solution which contains 2 projects: A Dll (class library) and a unit test project. Both projects are using NET 4.0.

DLL project uses Google Calendar API and I have installed from nuget console by using this:

> Install-Package Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 -Version 1.45.0.1928

DLL project is compiling correctly without errors and Google Calendar API is installed correctly as well on it.

Unit Test project has a reference to the DLL project. When I compile the Unit Test project I get errors saying:

> The type or namespace name could not be found.

when I try to access any object from the DLL above error message appears. In Unit Test project I have specified correct using clause.

Comment: Please, share your code and reproducible sample

Comment: Finally I have solved. I had to add below nuget packages to my Unit Test project: microsoft bcl build components, microsoft Bcl portability pack, Microsoft async and Microsoft HTTP Client libraries.

Comment: Also I would like to say that it is necessary to add these nuget packages to all the projects in the chain that depends on a project containing Google Calendar API,not only directly but also indirectly.For example,imagine you have project A which contains Google Calendar API implementations,then a project B that references project A,then another project C that references project B and finally a project D that references project C.You will need to add those nuget packages to all the projects on the chain, that is,to project B, C and D (not only to project B that directly references project A)